# Spring Boot (Spring JPA) app connects to Azure PostgrestSQL on local but not on Azure App Service

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, azure-webapps, azure-postgresql

All I did was follow the instructions on this Microsoft tutorial about [Using Spring JPA with Azure Database for PostgreSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-data-jpa-with-azure-postgresql).

I followed the tutorial *step-by-step*. It did work on local, but once I tried deploying to Azure App Service using the line:

```
mvn azure-webapp:deploy
```

I eneded up getting the following exceptions:

```
2022-06-18T14:21:47.174605421Z   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2022-06-18T14:21:47.174617722Z  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2022-06-18T14:21:47.174625622Z ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2022-06-18T14:21:47.174648222Z  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2022-06-18T14:21:47.174671422Z   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2022-06-18T14:21:47.174677723Z  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2022-06-18T14:21:47.181787036Z  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)
2022-06-18T14:21:47.181816137Z
2022-06-18T14:21:48.082651314Z 2022-06-18 14:21:48.066  INFO 159 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_312 on 159fae2381c4 with PID 159 (/local/site/wwwroot/app.jar started by root in /local/site/wwwroot)
2022-06-18T14:21:48.093277084Z 2022-06-18 14:21:48.092  INFO 159 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-06-18T14:21:54.072530883Z 2022-06-18 14:21:54.071  INFO 159 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-18T14:21:54.477825753Z 2022-06-18 14:21:54.477  INFO 159 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 310 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-06-18T14:21:59.990516309Z 2022-06-18 14:21:59.987  INFO 159 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2022-06-18T14:22:00.174128684Z 2022-06-18 14:22:00.172  INFO 159 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-18T14:22:00.183673849Z 2022-06-18 14:22:00.182  INFO 159 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
2022-06-18T14:22:01.165341623Z 2022-06-18 14:22:01.163  INFO 159 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-06-18T14:22:01.173184258Z 2022-06-18 14:22:01.172  INFO 159 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12300 ms
2022-06-18T14:22:03.002264679Z 2022-06-18 14:22:03.001  INFO 159 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-06-18T14:22:03.789681832Z 2022-06-18 14:22:03.788  INFO 159 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
2022-06-18T14:22:05.177355721Z 2022-06-18 14:22:05.176  INFO 159 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-06-18T14:22:06.574275239Z 2022-06-18 14:22:06.572  INFO 159 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-06-18T14:22:18.288356776Z 2022-06-18 14:22:18.286 ERROR 159 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
2022-06-18T14:22:18.288456678Z
2022-06-18T14:22:18.288470578Z org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
[removed multiple lines]

2022-06-18T14:22:18.289706498Z Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289713899Z  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289721599Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289729599Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289737099Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289744299Z  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289752499Z  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289760299Z  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289767799Z  at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289775600Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289783300Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.289790900Z  ... 58 common frames omitted

2022-06-18T14:22:18.313647791Z 2022-06-18 14:22:18.311  WARN 159 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

2022-06-18T14:22:18.313710892Z org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
2022-06-18T14:22:18.313719592Z  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.313749992Z  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.313759293Z  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
[removed multiple lines]

2022-06-18T14:22:18.314322302Z Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
2022-06-18T14:22:18.314329802Z  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.314337202Z  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
[removed multiple lines]

2022-06-18T14:22:18.334018625Z 2022-06-18 14:22:18.333 ERROR 159 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.345518313Z 2022-06-18 14:22:18.343  WARN 159 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.366638459Z 2022-06-18 14:22:18.365  INFO 159 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.415568461Z 2022-06-18 14:22:18.414  INFO 159 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :
2022-06-18T14:22:18.415659562Z
2022-06-18T14:22:18.415670862Z Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600163885Z 2022-06-18 14:22:18.599 ERROR 159 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600245087Z
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600273087Z org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600281587Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600288587Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600296388Z  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar!/:5.3.20]
[removed multiple lines]

2022-06-18T14:22:18.600490691Z Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600496791Z  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600503291Z  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600509391Z  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
[removed multiple lines]

2022-06-18T14:22:18.600625493Z Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600631693Z  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600638193Z  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600644493Z  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600650693Z  at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600656793Z  at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600663194Z  at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar!/:5.6.9.Final]
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600669394Z  ... 41 common frames omitted
2022-06-18T14:22:18.600675194Z
2022-06-18T14:22:18.721869679Z Wait for pid == 159 either returned successfully or was interrupted due to a signal 159
2022-06-18T14:22:18.723175201Z Done waiting for main process. GLOBAL_PID_MAIN=159.
2022-06-18T14:22:18.723529007Z Exiting entry script!


2022-06-18T14:22:20.321Z ERROR - Container spring-boot-complete-test-app-no-db_0_3410b247 for site spring-boot-complete-test-app-no-db has exited, failing site start
2022-06-18T14:22:20.558Z ERROR - Container spring-boot-complete-test-app-no-db_0_3410b247 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
2022-06-18T14:22:20.643Z INFO  - Stopping site spring-boot-complete-test-app-no-db because it failed during startup.
2022-06-18 14:22:18.286 ERROR 159 --- [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.


org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
[removed multiple lines]

2022-06-18 14:22:18.311  WARN 159 --- [main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata


org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.5.jar!/:42.3.5]
[removed multiple lines]

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
[removed multiple lines]

2022-06-18 14:22:18.333 ERROR 159 --- [main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2022-06-18 14:22:18.343  WARN 159 --- [main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2022-06-18 14:22:18.365  INFO 159 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-18 14:22:18.414  INFO 159 --- [main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :


Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-18 14:22:18.599 ERROR 159 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

This really tells me that there seems to be a problem with the deployment, since the same exact code works fine when deployed on local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it is *not enough* as of writing of this question to just modify the *application.properties* file as follows:

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://$AZ_DATABASE_NAME.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/demo
spring.datasource.username=spring@$AZ_DATABASE_NAME
spring.datasource.password=$AZ_POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Now, you will also have to establish the connection of the Azure App Service into the database by:

1. Going to Azure portal
2. Opening the Azure App Service instance you want to connect
3. Go to Settings > Service Connector
4. Click `Create` and select the database and provide credentials needed to connect to that database.

[Go to Azure portal > click the Azure App Service you want to connect to the database > create a connection in Service Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPHYR.png)